# How to get the following siblings of a complex xpath query

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have a complex html where I need to check a child node before knowing if I can get the siblings. For example:

```
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <a name="notme">
  </div>
</div>
<table>...<a> </table>
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <a name="pickme">
  </div>
</div>
<table>...<a> </table>
```

I need to get all  from the table following the `<div>` that contains `<a name="pickme">`

This is the xpath I have now:

```
 response.xpath('(//div[@class="test"]//a[@name="pickme"])/following-sibling')
```

So basically I look for a `div` with somewhere an `<a>` inside that has the correct name. Once I found that `<div>`, I get the next sibling of it and check inside.
How do I tell xpath that "following-sibling" is referred to the `<div>` and not the `<a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `div` instead of `a` and just check existence of `a` in XPath predicate, then you can easily add `following-sibling` axis in the path :

```
//div[@class="test"][.//a/@name="pickme"]/following-sibling::table
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know the use of predicates. One think I noticed in your solution is that if there are other table after the first one, it gets picked as well. If I add [1] at the end it should work correctly. am I right?